# Automapper exception when mapping JsonObject in .Net6 - "The node already has a parent"

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I'm trying to map a JsonObject (System.Text.Json) with AutoMapper 12.0.0

Source:

```
public record Request
    {
        public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
        public JsonObject AdditionalParameters { get; set; }
    }
```

Destination:

```
public record ResultsEvent
{
    public Guid RequestId { get; init; }
    public JsonObject AdditionalParameters { get; init; }
}
```

The code which getting an error is the following:

```
var resultsEvent = _mapper.Map<ResultsEvent>(request);
```

The error I get:

```
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The node already has a parent.
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_NodeAlreadyHasParent()
at System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.AssignParent(JsonNode parent)
at lambda_method319(Closure , Object , ResultsEvent, ResolutionContext )
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I saw the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305395/mapping-problem-for-json-object-array-in-net-6-automapper-the-node-already-ha) but I wonder if there is a more elegant way than setting it manually.

Just for clarity, with NewtonSoft.Json I don't get this error.

I tried to clone it in the AutoMapper profile and serializing/deserializing but nothing worked.

Comment: Would be great if you can provide some sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Yes show something that is reproducable. So add the profile with the actual mapping and some example data.

Comment: `CreateMap<JsonObject, JsonObject>().ConvertUsing(s => s);`

Comment: Hard o say without a [mcve] showing sample JSON and how `_mapper` is constructed, but the *The node already has a parent.* exception is thrown when trying to add a `JsonNode` that already has a parent, to another parent.  You may need to teach AutoMapper how to map JsonNode objects yourself.  See [Clone a JsonNode and attach it to another one in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71570877/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

The more elegant way is just configure additional map for the `JsonObject`

```
expression.CreateMap<JsonObject, JsonObject>()
          .ConvertUsing(src => JsonNode.Parse(src.ToJsonString(JsonSerializerOptions.Default), 
                                              null, default)
          .AsObject());
```